# Converting custom class object into an Object[]

Tags: c#, linq, collections, type-conversion, enterprise-library

This is an example of my custom class.

```
public class Application
{
    public string App_Name { get; set; }
    public string App_Number { get; set; }
    public string Sever_Name { get; set; }

}
```

I am using ExecuteNonquery from the Enterprise Library Data Block to call my stored procedure.

I am looking for a way, possibly with linq, to turn an object of type Application into an Object[] that can be passed into ExecuteNoneQuery which looks like this.

```
Database.ExecuteNonQuery Method (String, Object[])
```

This is an example of what I'd like to be able to do, but a conversion of application will need to occur before this will work.

```
internal void Update(Application application)
{
    int returnValue = 0;
    string sql = "somsesproc";
    DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("AppsConnectionString").ExecuteNonQuery(somsesproc,    application);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want the `Application` object itself within the object array:

```
object[] oa = new object[] {application};
```

Or if you want the *properties* split into an array:

```
object[] oa = new object[] {application.App_Name, 
                            application.App_Number, 
                            application.Sever_Name};
```

Comment: The second method is the best way to put it. Splitting the properties into an array but without manually doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to strip out all of the property values into an array of any arbitrary object:

```
public static object[] StripPropertyValues<T>(T obj)
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(obj))
            .ToArray();
}
```

Thus allowing you to write:

```
DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("AppsConnectionString")
    .ExecuteNonQuery(somsesproc, StripPropertyValues(application));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ExecuteNonQuery(somsesproc, new Object[] {application});
```

Comment: This isn't working.  

The new object needs to look something like~> object[] values = new object[] { App_name, APP_number, Server_name }; However, with your code it ends up looking like Object[] values = new object[] { application }.  

One method that would work is~> Object[] values = new object[] { application.App_name, application.APP_number, application.Server_Name }.  

However, I was looking for a more efficient/shorter way to do it, because in my actual project, the object will have 14 parameters rather than the 3 in the example I've given.